# Do I have access to the TCP/IP packet's details from the CGI level?

Tags: cgi, request, webserver, tcp

CGI scripts, for example web applications, operate on the CGI interface of the webserver.

Do I have access to details of the TCP/IP packets associated with a certain connection? For example, I can get "request" details, like the environment, remote host details, etc. But can I also read out, for example, the 16-bit id field of the TCP/IP packets associated with this connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're several layers of abstraction above the raw TCP packets. You can't access their content directly.

And there is no "TCP packet associated with this connection". A connection is a stream of packets that run both ways. Packets contents are also not necessarily delivered to user as-is - they can be aggregated or split to fit the receiving buffer.